# Spring JdbcDaoSupport

Tags: java, mysql, spring

please, help me! I've got the trouble.
I've next SQL query

```
SET @sql = '';

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT( 
      'getInterviewsNumber(\'', name, 
'\', vtable.position)',
' AS \'',
      name, '\''
    ) separator ','
  ) INTO @sql
FROM interview_portal.departments;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT distinct vtable.position,  ',@sql, ' FROM inter_count as vtable');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

It works well in MySQL workbench. But how can i execute this query and get ResultSet using Spring JdbcDaoSupport?
I've tried a lot of variants, but i got MySQLSyntaxErrorException.

Thanks for your help!

Here is my Exception

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [generalDispatcher] in context with path [/InterviewPortal] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SET @sql = ''; SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT ( 'getInterviewsNumber(\'', name, '\', vtable.position)',' AS \'', name, '\'')  separator ',') INTO @sql FROM interview_portal.departments; SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT distinct vtable.position, ', @sql, ' FROM inter_count as vtable'); PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT ( 'getInterviewsNumber(\'', name, '\', vtab' at line 1] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT ( 'getInterviewsNumber(\'', name, '\', vtab' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
```

Here is my code:

```
String sql = "SET @sql = '';" +
                " SELECT" +
                " GROUP_CONCAT(" +
                " DISTINCT CONCAT ( " +
                "'getInterviewsNumber(\\'', name, " +
                "'\\', vtable.position)'," +
                "' AS \\'', name, '\\'') " +
                " separator ',') INTO @sql " +
                "FROM interview_portal.departments;" +
                " SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT distinct vtable.position, '," +
                " @sql, ' FROM inter_count as vtable');" +
                " PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;" +
                " EXECUTE stmt;" +
                " DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;" ;
        getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(temp);
                //"ORDER BY " + query.getSortType().getColumnName() + ((query.isDescendingSort()) ? " DESC" : " ASC;");
        Object[] args = new Object[0];
        return getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, args,
                positionItemMapper);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you edit your question, adding you java code in order to let us see what the problem could be? And begging help is not necessary, you can just say "Hello, I have the following issue:"

Comment: Never paste strings to generate a query. Always use parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create a stored procedure with your SQL code, see [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).

Then you'll be able to call it with JDBC template:

```
jdbcTemplate.update("call PROC_NAME (?, ?)", param1, param2);
```

[Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) for more details.

Comment: I've already create it before. But I cannot execute this query.

Comment: I added it to my question

Answer (score 0):

Spring JdbcDaoSupport allows you to execute **one query at at time**. What you are trying to execute is a complete procedure. You can either store the procedure in MySQL and call it as suggested by cy3er or break it into individual operations.

If I correctly understand you have first a `SELECT ... INTO ...` operation that would result to an `update` and then a `SELECT ...` that would result in a `query`.

As you are in java, you should even test that first operation gives a correct result before doing the second.